# searching multiple patterns in awk

Tags: awk

I've a text file of thousands of lines

```
:ABC:xyz:1234:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:11818:AAA:BBB  
:ABC:xyz:6789:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:203450:AAA:BBB  
:EFG:xyz:11818:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:154678:AAA:BBB  
:HIJ:xyz:203450:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:154678:AAA:BBB  
:KLM:xyz:7777:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:11818:AAA:BBB  
.....   
....   
:DEL:xyz:1234:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:203450:AAA:BBB
```

I need to find more than one occurrence of the 9th column i.e the o/p should show

```
:ABC:xyz:1234:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:11818:AAA:BBB  
:KLM:xyz:7777:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:11818:AAA:BBB  

:ABC:xyz:6789:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:203450:AAA:BBB  
:DEL:xyz:1234:200:some text:xxx:yyyy:203450:AAA:BBB
```

I tried:

```
awk -F ":" '$9 > 2 {split($0,a,":"); print $0}'
```

this prints all the records.

Comment: Your 9th field appears to be 'AAA's. They are numbered from 1. And the program does what it is expected to...$0 denotes the entire line. Sometimes it is useful to write the pattern as 2.0 < (0.0+$9) so it is not taken as string comparison

Comment: @user1666959 You do forget that there is one field in front of  `:`, so ninth field is the number.

Comment: You are right. Doesn't affect the rest of the comment. awk takes it as string comparison..and the OP's code is confusing, the split is not relevant (ie nothing happens to 'a')...so I just threw in ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it in pure awk:

```
awk -F":" '{if( s[$9] ){ print } else if( f[$9] ){ print f[$9]; s[$9]=1; print }; f[$9]=$0 }'
```

Explanation:

- The "f" array stores values of the 9th column that have occurred at least once.
- The "s" array stores values of the 9th column that have occurred twice or more.
- If the 9th column has occurred before, print the first occurrence, and this line.
- If the 9th column has occurred twice or more before, print this line.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$9]++;next} cnt[$9]>1' file file
```

or if you don't want to parse the file twice:

```
awk -F':' 'cnt[$9]++{printf "%s", prev[$9]; delete prev[$9]; print; next} {prev[$9]=$0 ORS}' file
```

Comment: Simple and beauty :).  You can write the  `file file` as `file{,}`

Comment: @Jotne yes in some UNIX shells but idk what environment he's using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -F: '{++a[$9];b[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {split(b[i],c,":");if (a[c[9]]>1) print b[i]}}' file
```